# Python Pandas: memory issue when subsetting a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory, subset

I am working with some big `pandas` DataFrame. I realised that the memory usage (as monitored in `Win Task Manager`) didn't decrease when assigning a subset of one DataFrame to itself. For example, if there is a big DataFrame df which takes roughly `10GB` memory, after doing operations like below:

```
df = df[df['v1']==1]
```

or even

```
df = df.loc[0:10]
```

The memory usage line in Task Manager wouldn't change at all.

I have searched a while and read some posts here and there - but couldn't find a understandable reason or solution. Any help are appreciated!

Is there a way to reduce the memory usage? I read some posts suggesting reading less data in the beginning, but this solution seems to be quite difficult in my case.

Comment: What are you reading from? Are you familiar with `usecols`?

Comment: There are many possible reasons. Are you working in an IPython repl, by any chance?

Comment: @Jarad I used this to select only a few columns.. but the original df has too many rows rather than columns. In some cases, I need to work on the full but in some cases I need to work on a proportion of the rows.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think so, I work on jupyter notebook, any relationships?

Comment: Yes. Jupyter notebooks (and IPython generally) keeps a bunch of history variables around, so there are probably tons of references to your original data-frame preventing it form being garbage-collected.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks. I tried to explicitly call import gc and gc.collect().. the memory could be reduced somehow but still too high than expected as I tried then to set e.g. df=df.loc[0:3] and then call gc.collect() again - however this time the memory usage didn't change...

Comment: @xavierliu no, you don't understand, this wouldn't be helped by explicitely calling the garbage collector, the problem is **that your Ipython history maintains references to your data-frame so the garbage collector will not affect it!** Try `print(Out)` or `print(In)` or `print(Out[2])` or `print(_3)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see, thanks. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve the issue in this case?

Comment: Perhaps try to do `new_df = df<whatever>` then try [`%xdel`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-xdel) magic, so `%xdel df` Not sure that will be sufficient. You should avoid simply evaluating your data-frame to get a print-out, because that creates references to it in the histories.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that worked for me is deleting each column/row one by one inplace.

```
for x in range(0,10):
    df.drop(x, inplace=True, axis=0)
```